# golang reference struct in same package in another file

Tags: go

How to reference `MyStruct` in another file in the same `package` or folder?

Currently I get `undefined: MyStruct` when `go build lib/file_2.go`. I can run `go install` with no error, should I just ignore the build error?

These are my files:

`lib/file_1.go`

```
...
package lib
...
type MyStruct struct{
}
....
```

`lib/file_2.go`

```
...
package lib
...
{
m MyStruct
}
....
```

Thanks

Comment: Your current approach is it. It'll work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're asking the go tool to compile `lib/file_1.go`, you never mention `lib/file_2.go` so how is it supposed to know it should compile it?

From `go help build`:

```
Build compiles the packages named by the import paths,
along with their dependencies, but it does not install the results.

If the arguments are a list of .go files, build treats them as a list
of source files specifying a single package.
```

Comment: Thanks and you can do "go build file_1.go file_2.go"

Comment: @ChrisG., you can but shouldn't. You should normally specify packages (or nothing for the package in the current directory) to `go build` (or `go install` or `go test`). Specifying files should be considered an advanced feature only used if you have some special need. Among other differences/issues, `go build *.go` ignores build constraints and uses a different way of determining the output executable name.

Answer (score 19):

This command works for me

```
go run *.go
```

Actually this will compile all go file and run your main function. So this works well

Comment: Don't do this. Use `go build` and `go install`, they exist for a reason. In particular using `go run *.go` will fail if you have *_test.go files (which you should have!) and it will silently ignore `// +build` constraints which will either cause it to fail or behave in an unexpected way depending on how the build tags are used.

Comment: Also, this question is talking about a file in a package other than `main` so `go run` has absolutely no bearing whatsoever and makes this irrelevant and not an answer.

Comment: Thanks Dave C for clearing everything. You are right.
But this command works nice for small demo projects.

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to use `MyStruct` directly, since it is in the same package as its definition.

If you have any issue, sometimes it can help (for an IDE like [SublimeText](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) + [GoSublime](https://github.com/DisposaBoy/GoSublime), for instance) to do a `go install` *before* creating `lib/file_2.go`.
That way, `lib/file_1.go` is compiled and present in `GOPATH/pkg`, with `lib/file_1.go` definitions visible for `lib/file_2.go` to use during its compilation.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/getting-started, you should run:

```
go run .
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile the multiple files using the build command first.

```
go build
```

Now you can see a build file got generated with the given name or the folder name in case of default. Then run the binary.

```
./binary_file_name
```